# Properly registering services for multiple instances in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I currently have some service that has a field representing some ViewContainerRef and a method to set the value of this field.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
  public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef

  setViewContainer(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef
  } 

  //some magic code below that depends on the value of viewContainerRef
}
```

Then I have a abstract base class for each of my components to which the `SomeService` is injected into.

```
export abstract class AppComponentBase {
  viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
  someService: SomeService;

  constructor(injector: Injector){
    this.viewContainerRef = injector.get(ViewContainerRef);
    this.modalService = injector.get(ModalService);

    this.modalService.setViewContainer(this.viewContainerRef);
  }

  //other code that doesn't depend on anything above
}
```

And following this I also have few components, which use "magic code" from `SomeService`  and extend the `AppComponentBase`, also there could be multiple inherited instances on the single view.

First of all, after my page is fully loaded and every component completed instantiation will the `this.someService.viewContainerRef` be unique for each component or will it be the same?

In case it is single for each, how can I make it unique?

Comment: To make service unique for each component instance, you should [provide it to component](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services) instead of module. So you need to remove `providedIn: 'root'` in the service and add `@Directive({ providers: [SomeService] })` to `AppComponentBase`

Comment: @vitaliykotov anyway am I right about current realization so that viewContainerRef that is inside my service is not unique among inherited components?

Comment: yes, when you add `providedIn: 'root'` that means that service will be a singleton. So when components call `setViewContainer`, `viewContainerRef` property in service will  be overwritten. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjxhzw?file=src%2Fsome.service.ts) is example of creating multiple services

Answer (score 0):

You would have them to pointing on the same instance of the SomeService as you are injecting it in root it would be a singleton for application scope. If you want each component to have its own instance you can add it into providers array of @Component decorator providers.
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection